# Authentication failure won't resolve in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, authentication

today U1 started to throw an error when trying to connect.

At first I got a rather cryptic message (something with AUTH_FAILURE maybe?) upon which I found the following instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatToDoWhenAuthenticationFails

Because none of the 3 possible causes described there turned out to be the case, I decided to remove my computer from the list of authenticated computers. Login into the U1 account online and removing the computer was no problem but U1 still did nothing. Finally with the instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/HowDoIAddMyComputer I finaly got U1 to re-initiate the login/auth process...

But it kept failing to connect this time showing me the message:
"An exception representing an authentication failure"

So I decided to reset my password just to be sure.

Still, U1 does not connect, showing me the same message :(

What's up?

Comment: Today, trying to connect shows a different error:

Method "CreateItem" with signature "a{sv}(oayay)b"on interface "org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection" doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at => [Ubuntu One - Sync error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42429/ubuntu-one-sync-error/42475#42475)

For me, all I had to do was:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
```

Some folks have suggested this was not enough to correct their problem.  For them I suggested that they work though the entire sequence of commands.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kory :)  even though I cannot try this... I have moved to Fedora 15 with Gnome3 (I like it better than Unity) so I'm not even going to try UbuntuOne on it... However, I'll keep this in mind for when I come back to Ubuntu as soon as Gnome3 runs stable on it.